# Creating a dictionary to store pass and user

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary that stores all the inputs that are submitted. I am able to get one username and password and then store it but I want the program to continually ask for username and password and keep storing it in the dictionary. Eventually I want to write the loop that will check if certain passwords and usernames exist. I'm not sure but I think I would need a counter to allow continuous input from the user.

```
def login():
    username = input ("Username: ")
    password = input ("Password: ")
    data = { }
    data[username] = password
    print (data)

login()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to repeat something a bunch of times, you're probably looking for a for loop or while loop. In this instance you can change

```
login()
```

to

```
for i in range(100):
     login()
```

this will ask for Username and Password 100 times! If you really want to ask for it forever you could do something like:

```
while True:
    login()
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Good answer. But you might want to add some way to exit (without the user hitting Ctrl-C). In which case you either want to put the loop inside `login`, so it can do a `break` or `return`, or have `login` return a value, so you can do `while login(): pass`, or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the answer by @Bovard, move the `data = {}` initialization outside the `for` or `while` loop. Otherwise, you'll end up always resetting `data` to an empty dictionary.

Either:

- make `data` a global variable which login can access,
- or let login call another function which gets user input,
- or do the infinite/long loop inside `login()`:

  ```
  def login():
      data = {}
      while True:
          username = input("Username: ")
          password = input("Password: ")
          data[username] = password
          print(data)

  login()
  ```